# Is it possible to stop sqlite treating double quoted identifiers as strings?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

According to: http://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_keywords.html

SQLite3 will do what you expect if you do:

```
select "foo" from bar;
```

But, if the identifier doesn't exist:

```
select "non-existant" from bar;
```

It falls back (for compatibility with old versions I guess) to treating the quoted text as a string.

This causes problems for me, as I'm dynamically creating queries using quoted columns like this, and the latter behaviour returns nonsense results instead of throwing an error.

I'm writing python code, and using a module that wraps a PEP-249 Python Database API Specification v2.0 module, so I can put in database specific hacks where necessary.

Our backend database may change (and indeed, will probably be different for local testing and production at some point), so I want to keep the SQL itself standard if possible.

Is there any way that I can either:

- stop/turn off this behaviour
- easily/reliably detect that this has happened (and raise my own exception, say)
- workaround this somehow (I don't imagine replacing " in the sql with a non-standard equivalent is easy to do programatically in a safe manner)

Comment: +1 for trying to be standard compliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column names are prefixed with table names or aliases, they cannot be misinterpreted:

```
SELECT bar."foo", a."baz" FROM bar, blah AS a
```

When you handle multiple tables, it's likely that you need to use this anyway to avoid column name conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use quotes, use `[` and `]`

```
sqlite> create table blah (name text);
sqlite> select "something" from blah;
sqlite> select "name" from blah;
sqlite> insert into blah values ('hello');
sqlite> select "something" from blah;
something
sqlite> select "name" from blah;
hello
sqlite> select [something] from blah;
Error: no such column: something
sqlite> select [name] from blah;
hello
sqlite>
```

Attempt to programmatically kludge:

```
import re
from itertools import cycle

s = 'select "something" from blah;'
sel, cols, rest = re.match(r'(select)\s+(.*?)\s+(from\s+.*)', s).groups()
cols = re.sub('"', lambda g, I=cycle('[]'): next(I), cols)
print ' '.join( (sel, cols, rest) )
# select [something] from blah;
```

Comment: `[` and `]` aren't standard SQL though. When our database backend changes, we'd have to change all of our SQL.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser true - I was going for the kludge route to special case Sqlite3

Comment: but that kludge is at the wrong level. It needs to be in the shim between the application making queries (where the SQL is) and the database module, so I'd need to convert `"` to `[` or `]` programatically. As I say, I don't imagine this is easy to do in a safe manner.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser okay - well, I've put what I had in mind as a kludge, but whether it's viable or not, who knows...

Comment: Mind you - it also appears that Sqlite3 also allows the `\`` character, which could be more straighforward

Comment: But in either case, you have to take account of SQL like `insert into foo (text) values ('oh no, "quotes" in a string!');`

Comment: The regex is too restrictive; it doesn't take account of columns appearing in the where clause, or sub queries etc.

Comment: ` isn't standard SQL either.

Comment: Okay, re-compile your own SQLite3, don't use SQLite3 and just move to an RDBMS to start with, see about an ORM, or just re-think this in general...